# HTTPUtils deprecated .. what do I do instead?

Tags: java, android

I need to download icons from the OpenWeatherMap website, build a URL, download the image, save it to local storage and also check to see if they already exist. HTTPUtils is underlined in red and when I looked it up, it's no longer being used.  The Bitmap code was given to use by the professor.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(TEMPS);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            //this is what talks to the xml on the website
            xpp.setInput(inputStream, "UTF-8");

            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("temperature")) {
                        curr = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                        //tell android to call onProgressUpdate with 25 as parameter
                        publishProgress(25);

                        min = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "min");
                        publishProgress(50);

                        max = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "max");
                        publishProgress(75);

                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("weather")) {
                        icon = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon");
                    }
                }
                xpp.next();
            }

            //Start of JSON reading of UV factor:
            //create the network connection:
            URL UVurl = new URL(UV);
            HttpURLConnection UVConnection = (HttpURLConnection) UVurl.openConnection();
            inputStream = UVConnection.getInputStream();

            //create a JSON object from the response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            String result = sb.toString();

            //now a JSON table:
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            double aDouble = jObject.getDouble("value");
            Log.i("UV is:", ""+ aDouble);
            uv = aDouble;
//*****This is where I need help
            Bitmap image = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(IMAGE);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
                }

            image = HTTPUtils.getImage(IMAGE);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(icon + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            public boolean fileExistance(String weatherIcons){
                File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(weatherIcons);
                return file.exists();
                Log.i("File name:", ""+ file);
            }
            FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = openFileInput("C:/Users/kathy/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidLabs/app/src/main/res/drawable");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("Download this file", e.getMessage());
                }
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            publishProgress(100);

                Thread.sleep(2000); //pause for 2000 milliseconds to watch the progress bar grow

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: From which package? This doesn't seem to be anything standard

Comment: @LppEdd based on the name, it sounds like one of the Apache packages

Comment: @Zoe I don't think so. Never heard of that class. I think it's something found on the net

Comment: @Zoe Sorry.  I am working on a mobile app using Android Studio.  This is one of the java classes inside.  My bad.

Comment: @Kathy let me know which solution you decided to use.

Comment: @LppEdd turns out the prof made a mistake and I did need to use that line at all.  Love being confused for nothing 

Answer (score 1):

While I don't really understand which package `HTTPUtils` comes from, I think relying on the standard classes from the JDK and Android SDK is the way to go.

```
try {
    // Get an open Stream to the image bytes
    final InputStream stream = new URL(IMAGE).openStream();

    // Wrap the Stream in a buffered one for optimization purposes
    // and decode it to a Bitmap
    try (final InputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(stream)) {
        final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
        // Process the image
    }
} catch (final IOException e) {
    // Handle the Exception
}
```

You might want to extract an helper method, which simply returns the instantiated `Bitmap` variable.

Comment: Friendly reminder that Android doesn't have any classes from the JDK, technically speaking. The Android SDK isn't the same as the JDK

Comment: @Zoe my bad. You can see I'm not an Android developer by that ;)